# Template/Shell Solution in VS2010/TFS

Tags: visual-studio-2010

I've created a base solution shell in TFS (Silverlight, 6 projects for use with Prism, including .NET and SL business projects).  I'd like to use this as a template for future solutions.  When I try 'Save Solution as', in VS2010, it prompts me to unbind the solution from TFS, and I don't think I want to do that.  Any tips on the best way to accomplish this?

Answer (score 0):

You probably want to unbind it. When you copy the "template" solution into a new project, you add it to source control and apply the Bindings on the New Solution to Source Control. Unless you want the template to replace and existing project?

Answer (score 0):

When you're using "Save As", that's not a template - it's a solution file. Using "Save As" doesn't save a copy of the contents - it doesn't save the projects.